# Error Riak\Object dont want update column of table

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Hello i'am trying today to open project today and vs code give me that error

> PHP Fatal error: Cannot use Riak\Object as Object because 'Object' is a special class name in

and  go to check file on `D:\xampp\htdocs\location_symfony\vendor\doctrine\cache\lib\Doctrine\Common\Cache\RiakCache.php`
and have an error at the level on Object namespace

```
use Riak\Object;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`object` is reserved keyword since PHP 7.2, so I'd look for a newer version of `riak\*` package that has this fixed

Comment: I'd check/create issues at the repo: https://github.com/doctrine/cache/
It looks like Riak cache is deprecated there